# Differential equation $\frac{dp}{dt} = 0.5p - 380$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation $\frac{dp}{dt} = 0.5p - 380$ which describes a population over time.

I want to know if $p(0) = p_o$, all values of $p_o$ for which the population will go extinct in finite time. I solved the differential equations but after I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: What was the Solution you got ?

Comment: Solve for $p_0$ such that $p$ approaches $0$ in finite time.

Comment: I have $t = 2 ln(\frac{760}{760 - p_o})$ but I do not know how to interpret the values of $p_o$ for which it will go extinct

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = 0.5p - 380\to \\
\frac{dp}{( 0.5p - 380)} =1dt\\ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{dp}{( 0.5p - 380)}=\int_{0}^{t}1ds\\ \frac{1}{0.5}\ln( 0.5p - 380)|_{0}^{t}=s|_0^t\\2\ln(0.5p(t)-380)-2\ln(0.5p(0)-380)=t-0\\ 2\ln(\frac{0.5p(t)-380}{0.5p(0)-380})=t-0\\
\frac{0.5p(t)-380}{0.5p(0)-380}=e^{\frac{t}{2}}\\\frac{p(t)-760}{p(0)-760}=e^{\frac{t}{2}}\\p(t)-760=e^{\frac{t}{2}}(p(0)-760)\\p(t)=e^{\frac{t}{2}}(p(0)-760)+760$$ can you take over? now
Think about When $ e^{\frac{t}{2}}(p(0)-760)=-760$   This was my question years ago... you can use this link to visualize it.https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nkkgavdp8u

Comment: I also get this but how do I interpret this equation so I know for which values of $p_o$ the population will go extinct?

Comment: I would recommend completely solving the equation for $p(t)$ first.